# CSS background does not display using background property

Tags: css

If I use the following the background doesn't appear.

background: url('Background.jpg') cover no-repeat center;

If I use the discreet background properties the background appears correctly.

```
background-image: url('Background.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

Are they not equivalent?  Am I missing something obvious?
Ultimately I need to layer multiple images so I need to get the background statement to work.

Same result in Firefox 24.0 or Chrome browser doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure the path to Background.jpg is correct? Try loading it in a regular image tag if you aren't sure and don't know how to check in the dev tools.

Comment: Thanks Adrift the slash fixed it

Answer (score 3):

You have to separate `background-position` from the `background-size` property with a `/` when using the CSS3 [background shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background); instead use:

```
background: url('Background.jpg') no-repeat center / cover;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fqhmh/